# Rails 3.2.9 Routes to incorrect controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I am using devise and cancan in my app. Both are working.

I have a `User` model and I have just added *(using scaffolding)* a new model called `Purchase`.

Before the Purchase model was added i also have a dashboard controller *(which just shows a single page at the moment, `dashboard#show`)* and is the page that gets loaded after login  at `localhost:3000/dashboard`

When a user is not logged in, i can access `localhost:3000/purchases`. But when the user is logged in I cannot. I can access `purchase/1` but not `/purchases`.

Any idea what is going on here?  The error it gives me is

> "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"dashboard"}"

**Dashboard Controller**

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        authorize! :read, @user
    end

end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'static_pages#index'
  match '/about', :to => 'static_pages#about'
  match '/error', :to => 'static_pages#error'
  devise_for :users

  resources :users

  resources :dashboard

  resource :visitors, :only => :create # POST to visitor_path to create a visitor

  resources :purchases
```

> Rake Route

```
                    root        /                              static_pages#index
                   about        /about(.:format)               static_pages#about
                   error        /error(.:format)               static_pages#error
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
         dashboard_index GET    /dashboard(.:format)           dashboard#index
                         POST   /dashboard(.:format)           dashboard#create
           new_dashboard GET    /dashboard/new(.:format)       dashboard#new
          edit_dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id/edit(.:format)  dashboard#edit
               dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id(.:format)       dashboard#show
                         PUT    /dashboard/:id(.:format)       dashboard#update
                         DELETE /dashboard/:id(.:format)       dashboard#destroy
                visitors POST   /visitors(.:format)            visitors#create
               purchases GET    /purchases(.:format)           purchases#index
                         POST   /purchases(.:format)           purchases#create
            new_purchase GET    /purchases/new(.:format)       purchases#new
           edit_purchase GET    /purchases/:id/edit(.:format)  purchases#edit
                purchase GET    /purchases/:id(.:format)       purchases#show
                         PUT    /purchases/:id(.:format)       purchases#update
                         DELETE /purchases/:id(.:format)       purchases#destroy
```

Comment: seems like your dashboard does not relate to your purchases, is there a problem when dealing with the ability in cancan? Beside, it you want to restrict the dashboard from others, is it better to use before_filter :authenticate_user! as well?

Comment: Show us your `rake routes`

Comment: i edited up top to show the rake routes.
@Nich cancan works with other pages for me, i havent tried to use on the purchases yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singular must be `resource`, else `resources`

```
resource :dashboard
resource :visitor, :only => :create
```

or

```
resources :dashboards
```

depending in what the task is

Answer (score 0):

Since Dashboard is a singular resource you need to set it up as:

```
resource :dashboard
```

that's resource singular.

My guess is that on the purchases page for logged in users, you have something like `link_to "Dashboard", dashboard_path`, however set up with resources, the show action will always expect an id. Since you haven't provided one, you get a routing exception.

You can find a bit about singular resources here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources